# how to stop the page closing in the ionviewwillleave method

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, ionic-framework, toast

I would like with the ionviewwillleave method to stop the page closing and make this pop-up appear (with toast.service) to confirm the exit without modifying the form

```
  ionViewWillLeave(){
  this.toast.toastError('voulez-vous sauvegarder vos modifications?', 20000, [{
    side: 'end',
    text: 'Oui',
    handler: () => {
    }
  },
  {
    side: 'end',
    text: 'Non',
    handler: () => {
    }
  }
]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will work specially Toasts, Alerts.

I have Achieve it by:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
   if (confirm("Do you want to Leave?")) {
      // you code here. this will ask for confirmation.
   }
}
```